# .Net Core Analytics

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, logging, model-view-controller

Enter the site in .net core, I need to log the statuses such as the IP address of the person, which page he viewed, how many people are logged in per day, and show it in the admin panel. I researched about this subject, I came across something called IActionFilter, but I have no idea how I can do it, can you help me about the subject?

Comment: I did everything step by step as you described, but it doesn't work, the problem is as follows userLog.user_id = "", => this is not how it works and i have to give zero userLog.user_name = currentUser; and I also get this error: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException the error is throwing at this line of code:_dbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: This can be fix, first of all you have to decide whether it meet your requirement, if so then we can fix your problem. In that case share your problem where you encounter the the problem and your `dbContext` class and also user class

Comment: I want to do the same as you shared, everything I want is available there. I couldn't solve the problem, except for my main project, I wrote the codes in the same structure to try, but it gives the same error, I couldn't figure out where I did the problem. Can you open the project you wrote on github for me?

Comment: Thank you for your guide and sharing your code. but as I said, I got an error in some places, because I don't know how to solve it, I asked you again

Comment: No problem I will assit to resolve the current issue. Would you kindly add your details code here or post new question with error prone details code which you are trying to implement either is fine.

Comment: _dbContext.SaveChanges(); => Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'user_name', table 'CoreNTierDB.dbo.UserLogs'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: userLog.user_id =0; // Get your Login your Id Here => "" (when you do it like this, it doesn't recognize the bottom lines and gives a syntax error)
            userLog.user_name = currentUser;

Comment: No not this way, update your questions with the full line of code, because I will solve it tomorrow morning. Post in a way so that I can reproduce the issue from your given code . also add your user log class with sql table schema.

Comment: https://github.com/cnrgrsc/Analytics

Comment: Hello please check the update.

Comment: No problem, try to set accordingly within your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have came across the right concept which is `IActionFilter` that can help you to get there.

Now let's jump into your problem one by one.

***IP address of the person:***

You can get it by using two ways, `local IP` and `Remote IP`, so how can? Well here we go

```cs
 var remoteIP = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
 var localIP = context.HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress;
```

***Which page he viewed:***

For this scenario within `asp.net core` aspect we could consider everything by `controller` and `action` right? What I mean is whatevery we do within asp.net core lifecycle its nothing but either a `controller` and an `action` within the perticular `controller` are we together?

If so, then if we can get the `controller` and `action` information  then your this problem gone. So now the question how? Here is the solution

```cs
var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
var currentUser = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
string actions = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

***How many people are logged in per day:***

So now, once user login into your system you have the login information right? So count it writing some `Linq` or `SQL` then `order by perticular date` then you can get it easily: For example:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) TotalUserLoggedIn,
login_date

FROM user_log 
GROUP BY login_date
ORDER BY login_date
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Application DbContext:***

Your application db should to like this to keep the user records into database. In this context it would be like:

```
public class MvcAttendanceDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public MvcAttendanceDbContext(DbContextOptions<MvcAttendanceDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<UserLog> UserLogs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserLog>().ToTable("UserLog");
           
        }

        internal object Query<T>(string v, string name, int employeeId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

***appsettings.json:***

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=YourSQLServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

***Register Db Context On Startup.cs:***

You should register this service within the `ConfigureService` under `Startup.cs`

```
         services.AddDbContext<MvcAttendanceDbContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Now come to your point...

***But I have no idea how I can do it:***

Well, no worries man, I will show you the details implementations

***LogAnalyticsActionFilter:***

```cs
public class LogAnalyticsActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
        
           
            var user = context.HttpContext.User.Claims;
            var remoteIP = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
            var localIP = context.HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress;
            //Get Your Page Information
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            var currentUser = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            string action = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            var httpVerb = context.HttpContext.Request.Method;

            //Database Operation Context
            var _dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MvcAttendanceDbContext>();
            //User Log Object
            var userLog = new UserLog();
            userLog.user_id = "", // Get your Login your Id Here
            userLog.user_name = currentUser
            userLog.login_date = DateTime.Now;
            userLog.login_time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
            userLog.ip_address = localIP.ToString();
            userLog.page_name = action;
            userLog.controller = controller;
            userLog.http_verb = httpVerb;
            //Save the context
            _dbContext.UserLogs.Add(userLog);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            Debug.Write(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), context.HttpContext.Request.Path);
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
           
            var user = context.HttpContext.User.Claims;
            var remoteIP = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
            var localIP = context.HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress;
          
            //Get Your Page Information
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            var currentUser = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            string action = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            var httpVerb = context.HttpContext.Request.Method;

            //Database Operation Context
            var _dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<MvcAttendanceDbContext>();
            //User Log Object
            var userLog = new UserLog();
            userLog.user_id = "", // Get your Login your Id Here
            userLog.user_name = currentUser
            userLog.login_date = DateTime.Now;
            userLog.login_time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
            userLog.ip_address = localIP.ToString();
            userLog.page_name = action;
            userLog.controller = controller;
            userLog.http_verb = httpVerb;
            //Save the context
            _dbContext.UserLogs.Add(userLog);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            Debug.Write(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), context.HttpContext.Request.Path);
        }
        
    }
```

***Startup.cs:***

Just register the above `actionFilter` on `startup.cs` file like below:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
       config.Filters.Add(new LogAnalyticsActionFilter());
    });
```

***User Log Model:***

```
public class UserLog
    {
        [Key]
        public long ulogo_id { get; set; }
        public long user_id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        public DateTime login_date { get; set; }
        public string login_time { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
        public string page_name { get; set; }
        public string controller { get; set; }
        public string http_verb { get; set; }
       
    }
```

***User Log Controller:***

```
public class UserLogController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MvcAttendanceDbContext _context;

        public UserLogController(MvcAttendanceDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
        
            var userLog = _context.UserLogs.ToList();
            
            return View(userLog);
        }
    }
```

***User Log View:***

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCApps.Models.UserLog>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>User Log</h2>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Total User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()</th>
            <th>@Model.Count()</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               
                <th>
                  User Id
                </th>
                <th>
                   User Name
                </th>
                <th>
                   Login Date
                </th>
                <th>
                  Time
                </th>
                <th>
                   IP Address
                </th>
                <th>
                  Page Visited
                </th>
                <th>
                  Controller Name
                </th>
                <th>
                   Action Performed
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                  
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.login_date)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.login_time)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ip_address)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.page_name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.controller)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.http_verb)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

***Final Output:***

[image]

> ***Note:*** If you would like to take time more about `IActionFilter` you could have a look our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#implementation)

Hope it would help to guide you through.

> ***Update:*** Here is the [github link](https://github.com/kironiitdu/UserActivityActionFitler) of this project. To run the project please change the database connection string on `app.settings`
> file. After that run the script  on your database `DatabaseScript.txt` which you can get
> on `data folder`  or you can `add migration` command.
> then build the project and run.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply. But I'm having a problem with this code star
var _dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<CosarContext>();

i am getting error
error code: InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'BISAATAL.DataAccess.DatabaseContext.CosarContext' has been

I checked everything but couldn't solve the problem

Comment: You are getting this because you haven't  register your db.context service on your  startup.cs files. It should be like this `services.AddDbContext<CosarContext>(options => 
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourDatabaseConnectionString")));`

Comment: In case of any further assistance see the `Application DbContext:` and `Register Db Context On Startup.cs:` part on the solution, I have updated for you. Now just a matter on copy and paste.

Comment: I did everything step by step as you described, but it doesn't work, the problem is as follows
userLog.user_id = "", => this is not how it works and i have to give zero

userLog.user_name = currentUser;   

and I also get this error: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException

the error is throwing at this line of code:_dbContext.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

just by a quick search in Google, you can find some great predesigned solutions (i.e google analytics)

You can develop your own server-side analytics log store

for example:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1251484/Introducing-Server-Side-Analytics-for-ASP-NET-Core

another better and more scalable solution is to add the ELK stack to your project,
and then you can query your application data and show to the client whatever you want.

this problem has tons of solutions and you should research yourself what solution suits the best for your needs.